# .Net Core MVC Post parameter binding is null

Tags: ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an MVC controller responsible for the **Group** entity.

My `[HttpPost]` method handles the creation of a new Group. Inside the parameters I try to bind the request to a simple `GroupModel` DTO.

The problem is that the parameter is always ´null´. I also added `.AddNewtonsoftJson();` to my service collection.

**GroupController**

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] GroupModel group)
{
    var (result, groupId) = await _groupService.Create(group.Name, group.Roles);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        AddErrors(result);
        return Create();
    }
}
```

**GroupModel**

```
public class GroupModel
{
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Roles { get; set; }

}
```

**JS**

```
function create() {

    var group = new Object();
    group.name = getGroupName();
    group.roles = getSelectedRoles();

    /* Ajax request */
    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + 'Group/Create',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(group),
        dataType: "json",  
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Im totaly sure Im missing something, I've done this countless times but I just cant figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it maybe caused by the data format of `group`.`group.name = getGroupName(); group.roles = getSelectedRoles();`I add sample data to it and it worked.
Here is a worked demo:
GroupController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] GroupModel group)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<button onclick="create()">Create</button>
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function create() {

        var group = new Object();
        group.name = "a";
        group.roles = new Array();
        group.roles[0] = 1;
        group.roles[1] = 2;
    /* Ajax request */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(group),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        
    }
    </script>
}
```

Result：
[image]